# Edit a single point in LineSeries oxyplot

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am currently exploring oxyplot and wanted to edit a single point in my lineseries. (see image)
[image]

For example I want to edit the second point. I want it to be twice the size that it normally is or change the colour. Is that possible without enlarging/changing the colour of all the other points?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way arround it. I drew another graph (scatterseries graph) on the selected point.